Browser don't ask me to save username and password
I have a login form in html, php, css languages. I want to browser to ask me automaticly to save the username and password. But it is not working. I am singin in the portal but i can not save the username and password.
My codes like that:
    <?php
    if ($_POST and !empty($_POST['username']) and !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $sifre = $_POST['password'];
        $AD = $_POST['username'];
        $kontrol = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM Firma WHERE Kod = '$AD' and Parola = '$sifre' ")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($kontrol) {
            $_SESSION['admin']['login'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['admin']['id'] = $kontrol['ID'];
            $_SESSION['admin']['Firma_Adi'] = $kontrol['Firma_Adi'];
            $_SESSION['admin']['Tur'] = $kontrol['Tur'];
            $_SESSION['admin']['kod'] = $kontrol['Kod'];
            $_SESSION['admin']['yetkili'] = $kontrol['Yetkili'];
            $_SESSION['admin']['plasiyer'] = $kontrol['PlasiyerID'];
            /* ?><script>Swal.fire( 'Giriş İşlemi Başarılı', 'Başarıyla giriş yaptınız, 1 saniye içerisinde yönlendiriliyorsunuz.', 'success' );</script><?php */
            header('refresh: 0; url=' . $site . 'ozet');
        } else {
            ?>
            <script>Swal.fire('Hata', 'Kullanıcı adı veya şifrenizi kontrol ediniz.', 'error');</script><?php
        }
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="on" >
                                                    
                                                <div class="form-group">        
                                                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" autocomplete="username" class="form-control"
                                                            placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı"  required>
                                                            
                                                    </div>  
                                                
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    
                                                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" class="form-control"
                                                            placeholder="Şifre" required>
                                                            
                                                </div>  
                                                
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-main-primary btn-block">Giriş
                                                        Yap</button>
                                                    </div>  
                                                </form>

I tried autocomplete but it is not working. And I add form action"index.php" it is also not working. When i add action the page is not works correctly.

Your form is looking quite reasonable to me. Are you using the password manager of the browser itself? Which browser exactly? Can you give the OS, browser name and version? If you use another password manager, which one?

Some password managers may not work if you don't browse a real domain, like a localhost or IP address. Perhaps that's the case here? Basically, we need more information. The more the better....

I am using a real domain. And i try chrome on 4 different pc and mobile phone. The result is same. It is not working. I try this on windows and OS systems.

OK, a real domain, in Chrome, on Windows and other OS's. You didn't tell us if it's the password manager of Chrome itself, or a plug-in like 1Pass or ProtonPass. They all work slightly different. I'm also curious if autofill works for other sites on the same device? I tested your form on Windows 11 in Chrome and it worked immediately (with the build-in password manager). Make sure autofill isn't switched off in the settings.

You might be running into a caching problem here. Suppose you first created a form that looked like you wanted it to, and only later added things like autocomplete="username". It might be that your browser still shows the old cached page. There are 2 way to refresh a page: 1. Do a hard refresh in the browser. 2. By using no-cache headers. Note that the latter will not work once a page has been cached!

In order for it to be cached, I think I must have logged in before and made some changes after this stage. However, even when I log in from a completely different computer and with an internet connection that has never been logged in before, I still experience the same situation.

Could this code be the cause of the problem? header('refresh: 0; url=' . $site . 'ozet');

Yes, now that you mention it, it could be a problem. What happens if you comment that line out? Normally the password manager will ask you to save credentials on the page you get to when you submit the form. If you redirect away from that page immediately, it might never ask you. That could be it. I also noticed that $site seems to be undefined.

$site. Since it is defined in a different place, it provides direct redirection to the domain from there. This code works, but if it is as you say, I will need to make a different redirection. What kind of guidance should I give when I press the submit button on the form?

Modern website handle form submissions through AJAX calls. That means the page won't change until the form data has been processed in the background and a response was given by the server. What will happen then depends on the response. It could be a message telling the user to correct some input or it could be a redirection to another page. Double redirections after a form submission, like in your case, are not normal.
